# Index-Matching and assigning the matched value to a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, matching

I'm totally new with R and I'd like to perform some simple indexing through R.

I have a data frame with names on the first column and corresponding unique IDs on the second. I'd like to assign a specific ID to a particular variable and use it onward for data analysis. For Example:

```
names <- c('Kyle','Sophie','John','Peter','Julie','Carol')
IDs <- c('23513','15315','62352','25346','73424','03029')
df <- data.frame(names, IDs)
```

I've got a data frame like this, and want to assign a particular ID to a variable like:

```
Student_ID <- (sample formula to bring in an ID using a name, say "Kyle" and this formula
brings in '23513')
```

I'm extremely new to the coding environment so I don't even know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `with(df, IDs[names == "Kyle"])`

Comment: `df[df$names == "Kyle",]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the index of `student_name` in `names` column of data and get the corresponding ID back.

```
student_name <- "Kyle"
Student_ID <- df$IDs[match(student_name, df$names)]
Student_ID

#[1] 23513
#Levels: 03029 15315 23513 25346 62352 73424
```